# New meter socket

Tags: electrical, meter

I am relocating a meter socket, so I am installing a new one three feet down from the old one. What is an ideal meter socket for 200 amp service?

Comment: What your local power company suggests/allows.  What is the matter with the old one that it can't be moved?

Comment: Will you ever be getting solar panels? You might want one that is compatible with a 2nd outgoing socket

Comment: Who do you have for an electric utility?

Answer (score 3):

You should be checking with your power company. Each one usually has a list of approved meter cans that can be used on their system. You don't want to have them come out to connect to the line and load sides and then reject the meter can. Some companies might even provide a basic meter can.

Comment: They supply the meter, you supply the can to their specs, everywhere I've ever been.

Comment: @Ecnerwal   Florida Power and Light provided the cans up to ten years ago and still do for CT metering and residential overhead to underground conversions when they do a whole area at their expense.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- yeah, there are still a few holdouts that provide meter cans for single family residential services instead of expecting you to procure your own